# Updating the value of a variable

Tags: javascript

How to update the value of a variable in javascript?
    I have tried it using the code below,but it isn't working.
    I have took a button and a p tags with id's a,b,c.
    If x=0,John gets a point.
    If x=1,Rob  gets a point.
    If x=2,Lee  gets a point.
    Initially,when I run the code,i,j,k are being display
    Then,x updates,but i,j,k are not getting updated.
    That is if john gets a point for second time i is not being updated to 2.
    Please help me to solve this problem.
    See the code below.

```
    document.getElementById("but").onclick=function(){
        var x=Math.random();
        x=3*x;
        x=Math.floor(x);
        var i=0,j=0,k=0;
        if(x==0){
            ++i;
            document.getElementById("a").innerHTML="John:" +" "+i;
        }else if(x==1){
            ++j;
            document.getElementById("b").innerHTML="Rob:" +" "+j;
        }else if(x==2){
            ++k;
            document.getElementById("c").innerHTML="Lee:" +" "+k;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Too general of a question and too specific of an example.

Answer (score 1):

> That is if john gets a point for second time i is not being updated to 2

You're not doing anything anywhere in your code that knows about what's gone before. You're *overwriting* the content of the elements by assigning to `innerHTML` each time.

If you want to keep track of previous values, you'll either have to grab the value from the input before updating it (clunky), or track them separately, for instance in an object that's held outside the function:

```js
// An object to keep values in
var scores = {
  a: 0,
  b: 0,
  c: 0
};
document.getElementById("but").onclick = function() {
  var x = Math.random();
  x = 3 * x;
  x = Math.floor(x);
  if (x == 0) {
    ++scores.a;
    document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = "John:" + " " + scores.a;
  } else if (x == 1) {
    ++scores.b;
    document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = "Rob:" + " " + scores.b;
  } else if (x == 2) {
    ++scores.c;
    document.getElementById("c").innerHTML = "Lee:" + " " + scores.c;
  }
}
//
```

```html
<input type="button" id="but" value="Click me">
<div id="a">(blank)</div>
<div id="b">(blank)</div>
<div id="c">(blank)</div>
```

We can refactor that further to reduce the duplicated code, and to initialize the elements up front when the values are 0:

```js
// An object to keep values in
var scores = [
  {name: "John", score: 0, id: "a"},
  {name: "Rob", score: 0, id: "b"},
  {name: "Lee", score: 0, id: "c"}
];
scores.forEach(showScore);
document.getElementById("but").onclick = function() {
  var entry = scores[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
  ++entry.score;
  showScore(entry);
}
function showScore(entry) {
  document.getElementById(entry.id).innerHTML =
    entry.name + ":" + " " + entry.score;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="but" value="Click me">
<div id="a">(blank)</div>
<div id="b">(blank)</div>
<div id="c">(blank)</div>
```

Comment: If i can notice, object is maybe not necessary in this case, simple removing of var definitions outside of click function - should work. :) http://jsfiddle.net/664kgnnq/

Comment: @nevermind: Quite true, you don't *need* an object, no, but it helps when you take the optimization to the next level -- see the bit I was adding. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, yes, nice. :) Sri Harsha, no problem, but - take T.J. solution, it is better to go with good practices from the very start (unlike some of us)... :)